# Understanding the computation of IntensityCentroid?

Tags: image-processing

If I have an image `img`, and I ask `ComponentMeasurements` to return `"IntensityValues"` for the image:

```
m=MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[img]];
ivalues=ComponentMeasurements[{m,img},"IntensityData"];
```

How can I replicate the output of `ComponentMeasurements[{m,img},"IntensityCentroid"]`?

The challenge I'm having is understanding how to interpret a calculated intensity centroid from `"IntensityValues"` in the context of larger image with the overlayed morphological component?  Is it flipped or rotated?  It would be fantastic to see an example going from the raw `"IntensityValues"` data to the output of `ComponentMeasurements[{m,img},"IntensityCentroid"]` for the same morphological component.

Comment: Check out `ImageMeasurements`. I imagine it uses the same method as that under the hood to compute the intensity centroid or intensity values for each component. To replicate the result by applying `ImageMeasurements` on each component, this might be of help: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28826/adjusting-the-pixel-values-underlying-a-morphological-component-when-computing-a/28837

Comment: @Anon I was hoping for someone to show me how to manually compute the measurement, since I was having some trouble getting it right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
img     = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
m       = MorphologicalComponents[Binarize[img]];
ivalues = ComponentMeasurements[{m, img}, "IntensityData"];

cents = ({#[[2]] - .5, ImageDimensions[img][[2]] - #[[1]] + .5} & /@ 
        (Total[Position[m, #] (# /. ivalues)]/Total[(# /. ivalues)] & /@  Range[Max[m]]));
```

Testing:

```
Chop[cents - ComponentMeasurements[{m, img}, "IntensityCentroid"][[All, 2]]]
```

> {{0,0}, {0,0}, ... {0,0}}

Comment: +1, but it should be `ImageDimensions[img][[2]]`

Comment: @SimonWoods You're right of course. The image coordinates are always a source of bugs. I shouldn't test with square images! Thanks.