# Image-Processing/IntensityCentroid

Tags: image-processing

To get the center of mass of a grey scale picture I would like to use `ComponentMeasurements` with `IntensityCentroid`. However the points evaluated by the following script do not match with the expectations.

This is the "bubbles.png" test-Image i used:

[image: bubbles.png]

```
i = Import["bubbles.png"];
m1 = ComponentMeasurements[i, "IntensityCentroid"] /. Rule[_, x_] -> x;
points = Graphics[{PointSize[0.01], Red, Point[m1]}];
Print[Show[i, points, ImageSize -> 350]]
```

The output looks like this:

[image: bubbles_output.png]

Here I would have expected to get the center of the bubbles.

If I use "Centroid" instead of "IntensityCentroid" the output matches my expectation, but again I actually would like to have a brightness weighted result.

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit p.s. : Using the coordinate transformation (or however one might call it) from [HERE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30428/understanding-the-computation-of-intensitycentroid) did not work for me. I even got negative coordinates!?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the behavior you showed. [Running your code with `IntensityCentroid` exactly as you wrote it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LykaG.png) resulted in [this output](http://i.stack.imgur.com/GFUCT.png), which is probably what you wanted, but not what you got.

Comment: Thanks for replying! I was using Mathematica 8 before and had the opportunity to try it in Mathematica 10 now. However, in the new MM version it does work indeed!

Comment: Why do you write `Print[Show[i, points, ImageSize -> 350]]`? Try dropping the `Print`; do you not get the same result?