# What is the idiomatic way to operate on the components of an image separately?

Tags: image-processing

Suppose I have an image containing several morphological components and I wish to extract them as individual images (with sizes equal to their bounding boxes; these individual images shouldn't contain parts of neighboring components), then apply some image-processing functions to each of them *individually*, and finally combine them backward keeping the position of the each as it was in the original image. Note that bounding boxes of the components can intersect with each other.

Here is an example:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwfYD.png"]
```

> [image]

```
m = MorphologicalComponents[img];
cm = ComponentMeasurements[{m, ColorNegate@img}, {"MaskedImage", "BoundingBox"}];
newComps = ImageAdjust /@ DistanceTransform /@ ColorNegate /@ cm[[;; , 2, 1]]
```

> [image: output]

The question:

**How to assemble the transformed components `newComps` into the complete image?**

Comment: Is [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28837/731) of any help?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a `SparceArray` version of [Ali](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27331/ali-hashmi)'s [second](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144402/280) method which is expected to be more memory-efficient (at least for images of type `"Real"`):

```
{iW, iH} = ImageDimensions@img; 

Image[Total[
  Table[SparseArray[
    Band[1 + Round@{iH - #[[2, 2]], #[[1, 1]]} &@cm[[i, 2, 2]]] -> 
     ImageData[newComps[[i]]], {iH, iW}], {i, Length[cm]}]]]
```

> [image]

Procedural summation is even more memory-efficient:

```
Module[{sum = 0}, 
 Do[sum += SparseArray[
    Band[1 + Round@{iH - cm[[i, 2, 2, 2, 2]], cm[[i, 2, 2, 1, 1]]}] -> 
     ImageData[newComps[[i]]], {iH, iW}], {i, Length[cm]}]; Image[sum]]
```

> [image]

```
Image[Fold[Plus[#1, 
    SparseArray[
     Band[Round@{-cm[[#2, 2, 2, 2, 2]], 1 + cm[[#2, 2, 2, 1, 1]]}] -> 
      ImageData[newComps[[#2]], Automatic], {iH, iW}]] &, 0, Range[Length@cm]]]
```

> [image]

---

Here is how this method can be applied to a three-channel RGB image (the purpose here is to `ImageAdjust` the components of the image independently from each other):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7zdU.png"]
```

> [image]

```
m = MorphologicalComponents[img, .3];
cm = ComponentMeasurements[{m, img}, {"MaskedImage", "BoundingBox"}];
newComps = ImageAdjust@ImageMultiply[RemoveAlphaChannel@#, AlphaChannel[#]] & /@ 
  cm[[;; , 2, 1]]
```

> [image: output]

```
{iW, iH} = ImageDimensions@img;

Image[Total[
  Table[SparseArray[
    Band[Round@{1 + iH - #[[2, 2]], 1 + #[[1, 1]], 1} &@cm[[i, 2, 2]]] -> 
     ImageData[newComps[[i]]], {iH, iW, 3}], {i, Length[cm]}]]]
```

> [image]

---

Combining everything into one function:

```
assembleComponents[newComps_, boundingBoxes_, {iW_, iH_}] := 
 Module[{sum = 0, iCh = ImageChannels[newComps[[1]]]},
  If[iCh == 1, 
   Do[sum += SparseArray[
      Band[Round@{iH - boundingBoxes[[i, 2, 2]] + 1, boundingBoxes[[i, 1, 1]] + 1}] -> 
       ImageData[newComps[[i]], Automatic], {iH, iW}], {i, Length[boundingBoxes]}],
   Do[sum += 
     SparseArray[
      Band[Round@{iH - boundingBoxes[[i, 2, 2]] + 1, boundingBoxes[[i, 1, 1]] + 1, 1}] -> 
       ImageData[newComps[[i]], Automatic], {iH, iW, iCh}], {i, Length[boundingBoxes]}]]; 
  Image[sum]]
```

Usage:

```
assembleComponents[newComps, cm[[;; , 2, 2]], ImageDimensions[img]]
```

> [image]

Comment: Fun,since we want to restore the image,then we have no the information of `img`.Then we cannot use `ImageDimensions@img`?

Comment: @yode No, you misunderstood the question. We don't need to restore the original image, we have it. We need to assemble *processed* components into the complete *new* image in a way that each of them is placed exactly where it was in the original image.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Neat !! +1

Answer (score 5):

```
Module[{seg, img = img, cm, newComps, func},

seg = MorphologicalComponents[img];
cm = ComponentMeasurements[{seg, ColorNegate@img}, {"MaskedImage","BoundingBox"}];
newComps = ImageAdjust /@ DistanceTransform /@ ColorNegate /@ cm[[;; , 2, 1]];

func[matrix_, {ind_, imgs_}] := 
Block[{mat = matrix, cellindpos, smallImgData, vals},
cellindpos = Position[seg, ind];
smallImgData = ImageData@imgs;
vals = Extract[#, Position[#, x_ /; x != 0]] &@smallImgData ;
ReplacePart[mat, Thread[cellindpos -> vals]]
];

Fold[func, ConstantArray[0, Reverse@ImageDimensions@img],
Thread[{Range@Length@newComps, newComps}]]] // Image
```

[image]

Comment: This method assumes that the indices of each of the components do not change during processing of the subimages. This assumption is very restrictive and isn't correct in general. Your [second method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144402/280) is much better since it doesn't imply such an assumption and at the same time is *much* simpler and more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

An `ArrayPad` version of [Ali](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/27331/ali-hashmi)'s [second](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/144402/280) method:

```
data = KeyValueMap[
  Round[Transpose[#2]] -> ImageData[#1] &, <|Thread[newComps -> cm[[All, -1, -1]]]|>];
dim = ImageDimensions[img];
Image[Plus @@ (ArrayPad[Values[#], {{dim[[2]] - Keys[#1][[2, 2]], 
   Keys[#1][[2, 1]]-1}, {Keys[#1][[1, 1]]-1,dim[[1]] - Keys[#1][[1, 2]]}}] & /@ data)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Since we *have* `img`, you should simply use `dim = ImageDimensions[img]` for obtaining the dimensions of the original image. Then your solution won't be "durty" anymore. ;)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Pretty a little,thanks.

Comment: I've added a short description of your method, I hope you don't mind. :)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Not at all,be my guest.But actually I havenot see the Ali's answer.If I have,I would not post it. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
{comps, boxes} = Module[{seg, img = img, cm, newComps, bounds},
seg = MorphologicalComponents[img];
cm = ComponentMeasurements[{seg, ColorNegate@img}, {"MaskedImage","BoundingBox"}];
bounds = cm[[All, 2, 2]];
newComps = ImageAdjust /@ DistanceTransform /@ ColorNegate /@ cm[[;; , 2, 1]];
{newComps, bounds}];

{iW, iH} = ImageDimensions@img

ImageAdd[MapThread[ImagePad[#1, {{#2[[1, 1]], iW - #2[[2, 1]]}, {#2[[1, 2]], 
  iH - #2[[2, 2]]}}] &, {comps, boxes}]]
```

[image]

Comment: This method uses `ImagePad` and since the approach is different hence posting it as a separate answer. Also the image obtained from this and the previous answer are both same (tested using `SameQ`)

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov please feel free to modify the answer. will be happy to see the modification !

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov at the end of both methods we can replace all background pixel values to the desired colour

Answer (score 2):

If instead of `"BoundingBox"` we request `"Mask"` the solution becomes more elegant and idiomatic:

```
cm = ComponentMeasurements[{m, ColorNegate@img}, {"MaskedImage", "Mask"}, 
   "PropertyAssociation"];

newComps = ImageAdjust /@ DistanceTransform /@ ColorNegate /@ cm["MaskedImage"];

pos = Min /@ Transpose[#["NonzeroPositions"]] & /@ cm["Mask"];

Image[Total[
  Table[SparseArray[Band[pos[[i]]] -> ImageData[newComps[[i]]], 
    Reverse[ImageDimensions@img]], {i, Length[newComps]}]]]
```

> [image]